# Multiple blocks in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a page that shows articles and event dates. I have the code set up for block content working for the article, but I can't figure out how to make the second block of content appear on the page.

These are my models:

```
class NewsLetter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this is the code for the second block of content I am trying to show:

```
{% block events %}
<div class="w-full bg-white shadow flex flex-col my-4 p-6">
    <p class="text-xl font-bold pb-3">Events Calendar</p>
    <hr>
    {% for event in object_list %}
    {{ event.title }}
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="#"
        class="w-full bg-green-600 text-white font-bold text-sm uppercase rounded hover:bg-green-500 flex items-center justify-center px-2 py-3 mt-4">
        Sign Up
    </a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My views.py file looks like this:

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import NewsLetter, Event

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = NewsLetter
    template_name = 'home.html'


class EventView(ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

The solution has to be simple, but I can't see it in the Django docs. Can someone please help. And please remember, the answer to a similar question posted 3 years ago may not work today - so please don't send me to some antiquated version of this question.

Thank you

Comment: The code I posted displays the Newsletter title. I changed it to: {% for event in object_list %}
    {{ event.name }} and that part of the display goes blank
    {% endfor %}

Comment: looks like `object_list` probaby contains `Newsletter`s instead of `Event`s. How do you pass data to the view? Can you provide the relevant view(s)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My views look like this:from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import NewsLetter, Event



class HomeView(ListView):
    model = NewsLetter
    template_name = 'home.html'


class EventView(ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'home.html'

Comment: pleas [edit] your question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry about that. Just edited

Comment: `{{ event.title }}` does not seem to make much sense, since an `Event` has no `title`. Are you sure you trigger the `EventView` and not just the `HomeView`?

Comment: I changed it to {{ event.name }} and nothing displayed. When I have {{event.title }} I get the Newsletter title. So something is working, but not the way it should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221738/discussion-between-loudeye-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: well that means that `object_name` is a collection of `NewsLetter`s, and you thus trigger the `HomeView`, and *not* the `EventView`. Notice that if you specify the same `template_name` it does *not* mean that both views are processed. It simply means both views will use the same template to generate a response.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I read the docs regarding the image files, and the docs don't have an answer as to why they don't display. I have gone over and over the code and can't see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the view pass both data about the `Newsletter`s and the `Event`s to the template. For example with:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = NewsLetter
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def events(self):
        return Event.objects.all()
```

in the template, you then have a block to render the `NewsLetter`s:

```
{% for newsletter in object_list %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

and another block where you can render the `Event`s with:

```
{% for event in view.events %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I read the docs, and the docs don't have an answer for why my images don't display

Comment: @LoudEye: on production the Django server does not serve images, so you will need to configure nginx/apache/... for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production  . On development you will need to configure the `url_patterns` to have patterns that serve media/static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: I read those docs and did everything like they explain. But it still does not work.

Comment: @LoudEye: well do you see requests in the console for these media files? Do these requests trigger the views to serve media files? Is `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: It works when Debug = True It does not work when Debug = False

Comment: The files are loading in, but not displaying.

Comment: @LoudEye: but as said, for `DEBUG = False`, Django does **not** serve media/static files since that is considered inefficient and likely unsafe. You will have to configure the apache/nginx/... server to serve media/static/... files.

Comment: My Apache files are set up exactly like the docs in Apache tell me to set them up. I just don't get it. Surely there is a better solution than, read the docs if the docs don't work.\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221835/discussion-between-loudeye-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: @LoudEye: what exactly can you see in the browser console? and in the Apache logs? I think you should ask a new question and include the logs together with (parts of) the apache config. Right now it is (close to) impossible to help.

Comment: Do you know how to order by anything other than date posted for the def events method you helped me with earlier?